# A* algorithm example explained

Tags: trees, search-algorithms

I am trying to understand A star algorithm. I am aware that it follows the sum of the current cost and heuristic, therefore `f(n) = c(n) + h(n)` in order to expand a new node. So every time the code with the smallest f(n) from the root is expanded. However, I am confused about the backtracking of the algorithm when it does not find the best solution. I tried to follow the example explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAoBeujec74). Therefore, by only using the f(n) the algorithm should have expanded: S-B-C-G. Firstly B then C and then G. Then declare that find a solution. How, the backtracking works?

The example is as follows:
[image]

In the left, there is the graph and in the table is the heuristic cost. What is going to be the a star expand in this graph?

Comment: You mean backtracking, not backpropagation.

Answer (score 1):

A* doesn't backtrack. It just keeps expanding the node with the least value of $f$ until it finds a solution. The properties of the heuristic used guarantee that the first solution found is optimal.

Comment: That is what I want to believe. But the example confused me. Instead of going directly to the best solution based on the heuristic, algorithm navigates through the other nodes too.

Comment: It shouldn't then go S-B-C-G directly based on the heuristic?

Comment: Please include the example directly in your question. I don't have time to watch a 22-minute video.

Comment: I include the example in the image in the question. My question is why A star does not go directly to S-B-C-G that is the intuition of the heuristic + the cost but it keeps in the fringe and continues to S-A-B-C-G